# nodejs express 3 framework session destroying issue

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables

I'm using nodejs with Express 3 framework and I have an issue with deleting one specific session, here is the code I'm using :

```
app.js 

var express  = require('express');
................
................
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret : 'asxcfrgth'}));
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/User', function(req, res){

req.session.login = "Invalid username";
req.session.password= "Invalid password";

console.log(req.session.login);
console.log(req.session.password);

req.session.destroy();
});
```

`req.session.destroy` will delete all my sessions so is there a way to only destroy the first session and leave the second one? I want to avoid using this :

```
req.session.login ="";
```

to empty the session variable, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to delete a session variable is to set it to `null`.

```
req.session.login = null;
// this also works
delete req.session.login;
```

The function `destroy()` is for removing the entire session.